# DynamoDB Read Capacity way over the limit but only on one table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have 6 DynamoDB tables set up for use as data sources for my iOS app. They all get called from the client near enough the exact same amount when someone uses the app but for some reason one table if getting crazy spikes in reads and going way over the read capacity and causing a `provisioned throughput for table exceeded` error.

The app only has a very small number of users in general (below 100).

The offending table metrics look like this:

[image]

But all the other tables look like this:

[image]

Any thoughts on what might be causing this? The code for making requests client side is all the same. They are seemingly all set up the same in the API using lambda and API gateway. What am i missing?

Comment: are you doing scan on the table by any chance instead of query

Comment: I am yes. I need to get the full data set of the table. All my other tables are fine through with the same kind of call. Some have massively bigger data sets and no troubles on them.

Comment: scans are supposed to take more rsus. Did you consider designing your system with query but no scans?

Comment: I guess that's something i should look into then. Just seems strange that it only happens on one of the smaller tables.